# How is a unidirectional lamina transversely isotropic?

Tags: material-science, continuum-mechanics, solid-mechanics

[image]

What I don't understand specifically is that if there happen to be more fibers in the $x_2$ direction than the $x_3$ direction, wouldn't that make the material properties in those directions different? That would violate the transverse isotropy.

I'm thinking that the opposite ought to be true. The material properties along the fibers should be the same and different in the transverse directions.

I would appreciate it if the answer was given in such as way that it relates physically to the situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to distinguish between a microscopic and a macroscopic point of view. The diagram is only a symbol for a lot of fibers evenly distributed in the $x_2-x_3$ plane. The material itself is transverse isotropic. But if you are creating a flat-bar with this material, then the flat-bar as a whole is clearly not transverse isotropic anymore. It would be orthotropic. 
For example, steel is isotropic(microscale) but an I-beam out of steel(macroscopic) isn't.